# adding a scroller around a component tag

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

i have a group tag as given below but i am getting the error:'Scalar value nodes may not be state-specific'

```
<s:Group includeIn="newTask,branchingGroup,model_chain,model,condition">

    <components:NewTask id="taskId" includeIn="newTask"/>
    <components:NewBranchingGroup id="branchId" includeIn="branchingGroup"/>
    <components:NewModelChain id="modelId" includeIn="model_chain" width="100%"/>
    <components:Condition id="conditionId" includeIn="condition"/>
    <s:Scroller>
    <components:NewModel id="modelNId" includeIn="model" width="100%"/>
    </s:Scroller>

</s:Group>
```

actually, i got this error as a result of trying to add a scroller component around the last components tag. Is there anyway i could avoid this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have probably already solve this by now but I will answer it for future reference.

You are not allowed to have a state-specific (includeIn) element inside the scroller. I recommend moving the includeIn to the scroller instead.

```
<s:Scroller includeIn="model">
   <components:NewModel id="modelNId" width="100%"/>
</s:Scroller>
```